# What is the performance/logical difference between jsonb_path_match and ->> in where clause

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I am trying to query FHIR data in a PostgreSQL database. The data is stored in jsonb field. Though the following queries yield the same result, I would like to know if there are any major differences in terms of performance or execution plan.

Query 1 - Using `->>` operator

```
SELECT resource->'subject' FROM resourcetable 
WHERE resource ->> 'resourceType' = 'MedicationRequest' AND resource ->> 'status' = 'active';
```

Query 2 - Using jsonb_path_match function

```
SELECT jsonb_path_query(resource, '$.subject') from resourcetable 
WHERE jsonb_path_match(resource, '$.resourceType == "MedicationRequest"') 
AND jsonb_path_match(resource, '$.status=="active"');
```

Comment: What happens when you try both?

Comment: Same result; I am mostly interested in the performance and execution aspect

Comment: You need to to compare execution plan using `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` ouptut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try it on your own data and see.  If you use `EXPLAIN` before the query text, you will get the execution plan.  If you put `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` before the query, it will actually run that plan and report the timing and statistics.

Your first formulation might benefit from a functional index defined like so:

```
create index on resourcetable ((resource ->> 'resourceType'),(resource ->> 'status'));
```

Your second formulation can't benefit from an index, but if you rewrite it into operational format:

```
SELECT jsonb_path_query(resource, '$.subject') from resourcetable 
WHERE resource @@ '$.resourceType == "MedicationRequest"'                       
  AND resource @@ '$.status=="active"';
```

Then it can benefit from an index defined as:

```
create index on resourcetable using gin (resource jsonb_path_ops);
```

The index defined without `jsonb_path_ops` would also be usable, but is probably less efficient.

You could also rewrite the condition to use JSON_PATH's `&&`, rather than SQL's `AND`.

This second index can also be used on a query that uses containment `@>` rather than json_path `@@`, which I find less confusing.

```
SELECT resource->'subject' FROM resourcetable 
WHERE resource @> '{"resourceType": "MedicationRequest", "status":"active"}';
```

Finally, your two queries actually return different results under some conditions, like if a row matching the WHERE does not have a key "subject".

Comment: I have experienced the last point you have mentioned regarding the difference of result. That is the most important different between the two approach, I guess. Also, can the first approach also get benefited from the gin index?

Comment: The first approach cannot directly benefit from the gin index.  You can rewrite it into containment query which can (see edit) but at that point is it really still the same thing as the first approach?

Comment: Why would postgres make such a difference between a `jsonb_path_match` and a `@@` call?

Comment: @Bergi  It was an ancient decision that indexes only work with operators, not functions.  I was not around for it.  I think it might have been 'fixed' in version 12 with the introduction of function planner support functions (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/xfunc-optimization.html), but very little of the historical code was rewritten to hook into this capability.